# Insert record and return Id in a SQL UDF?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a user defined function to insert a new record and return the Id, is this possible and how do I do it?

I have tried creating a function with the insert statement but I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid use of the side-affecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.
```

I am using SQL server 2008.

**UPDATE SQL:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNewBookingReference()

RETURNS int

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO BookingReference
(CreatedTime, CreatedByUserId)
VALUES
    (GETDATE()
    ,10)

RETURN @@IDENTITY

END
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have??

Comment: Just as an aside: I would strongly recommend using SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY - if you happen to have triggers on your tables, you might end up getting the wrong ID back from @@IDENTITY

Comment: thanks marc was just reading about that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL Server, user-defined functions *cannot* change database state. You will have to use a stored procedure with an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table1(name, age) values('xyz', 2);
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                // Check if new identity is needed.
                if (getId)
                {
                    // Execute db specific autonumber or identity retrieval code
                    // SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- for SQL Server
                    // SELECT @@IDENTITY -- for MS Access
                    // SELECT MySequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL -- for Oracle
                    string identitySelect;
                    switch (DataProvider)
                    {
                        // Access
                        case "System.Data.OleDb":
                            identitySelect = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
                            break;
                        // Sql Server
                        case "System.Data.SqlClient":
                            identitySelect = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
                            break;
                        // Oracle
                        case "System.Data.OracleClient":
                            identitySelect = "SELECT MySequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL";
                            break;
                        default:
                            identitySelect = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
                            break;
                    }
                    command.CommandText = identitySelect;
                    id = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                }
```